# Testing ControllerAdvice with AutoConfigureMockMvc and CompletableFuture

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-test, completable-future

I have added a REST controller returning CompletableFutures to a project using a ControllerAdvice to translate exceptions into error DTOs.

My controller doesn’t throw the exceptions, wrapping them into failed CompletableFutures and returning these.

When running the full application and manually testing it works as expected, but in my tests the mockMvc won’t trigger the advices and always return HTTP 2xx.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my test was not correct (or, to put it another way.. the testing framework is not designed as I expected ;)

When testing controllers returning CompletableFutures one needs to use asyncDyspatch as in

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/samples/standalone/AsyncTests.java

Answer (score 0):

If you have a standalone setup of `MockMvc`, then you need to specify the controller advice to be used (if any) while creating the mockMvc instance as follows:

```
MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
            .setControllerAdvice(new YourControllerAdvice())
            .build();
```

The reason for this is that you don't have a context here for spring to detect the controller advice.

Comment: Eh but I’m not using a builder, the mockMvc is Autowired (I basically copied the example from the Spring site) and it works if I throw the exceptions from the Controller. It doesn’t if the exception is delivered via a failed CompletableFuture.

Comment: I think you may need to create a test configuration class and add the annotation `@EnableWebMvc` to it to make spring import Spring MVC config

Comment: But if in your test you don't need spring context, then I would recommend that you use a standalone setup of MockMvc instead